# Lost all drives I had in Windows

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

I installed a new OS on my Lenovo laptop which had Windows 8.1.

While installing I was given options for partitioning. I lost all drives which were present in my Windows system. I am unable to see the drives in Ubuntu, it's just showing the partitioned part and rest of memory as free space

Are those drives lost permanently after partitioning? Can I restore them somehow?

Comment: For the future, **(and please don't take this the wrong way)** don't mess with things like partitioning if you don't know what they are. If you don't understand what something does, often a 5 minute Google search will help you understand.

Comment: Will you edit your question and give the output of: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l`  .  If you have valuable unreplaceable data on those partitions and are sure your partitions have been overwritten, you would best use your computer, only from the LiveUSB while you work to recover data from those partitions.  It would be best to install Ubuntu on a different hard drive, or USB Drive, while you work to retrieve your data from your current drive.  It's possible to install the OS on a Pendrive and use it as a regular system installation.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to recover all partitions. Don't format partitions again and again and don't transfer any data in it. Otherwise it will be difficult to recover.